# set wallpaper to the device without crop or zoom in

Tags: java, android

When I set an image from my app to be as background for the device, the device zoom in the image and crop it, but I don't want that, I want to set the image as the same size for it.

here is a short video explaining what I mean "just 15 sec" [the short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=FiU-uxBjQSA&app=desktop)

**hint: the first one is my app, second is Zedge app, the same photo.
so I want my app to like edge app when set image as wallpaper**

**Here is my code**

```
item_home_image = findViewById(R.id.item_home_image);
item_home_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (checkPermission()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("imageUrl");
        Picasso.with(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this).load(url).into(new Target() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this);
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toasty.normal(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "تم تغيير الخلفية بنجاح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                Toasty.error(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "فشل تحميل الصورة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                Toasty.normal(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "جاري التحميل", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
 }
});
```

**image when set it from my app**
[image: image when set it from my app]

**image when set it from Zedge app**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, and it is better than this

```
    // Set Home wallpaper the image
 public void setHomeWallpaper () {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            String bitmapPath = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "", null);
            Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA).setDataAndType(bitmapUri,  "image/jpeg")
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    .putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.background)));
            Toast.makeText(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "قم بإختيار التطبيق المناسب لتعيين الصورة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void getBitmapFromURL(String path) {

        Glide.with(WaalDetail.this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(path)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        try {
                            WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);
                            Toast.makeText(WaalDetail.this, "Set wallpaper successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

this is works for me perfectly.

Comment: The problem is not with the library have used, Picasso or glide, I think it is in scale type wallpaper, also "I used your codes and the problem is steel".